# compare value of the current index to the value of next index in Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare the value of the current index to the value of the next index in my pandas data frame. I'm able to access the value with `iloc` but when I write an if condition to validate the value. It gives me an error.

Code I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [2.5, 1.5, 3 , 3 ,4.8 , 4 ]})

trend = list()
for k in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[k+1] > df.iloc[k]:
        trend.append('up')
    if df.iloc[k+1] < df.iloc[k]:
        trend.append('down')
    if df.iloc[k+1] == df.iloc[k]:
        trend.append('nochange')

dftrend = pd.DataFrame(trend)


ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried assigning the `iloc[k]` value to a variable "current" with `astype=int`. Still I am unable to use the variable "current" in my if condition validation. Appreciate if somebody can help with info on how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error becauce

`df.iloc[k]` gives you a `pd.Series`.

You can use say `df.iloc[k,0]` to get the `Col1` value

Answer (score 0):

So, what I have done is I have converted that particular column into a list. Instead of working directly from the Series object returned by the dataframe, I prefer converting it to a list or numpy array first and then performing basic functions on it.
I have also given the correct working code below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [2.5, 1.5, 3 , 3 ,4.8 , 4 ]})
trend = list()
temp=df['Col1'].tolist()
print(temp)
for k in range(len(df)-1):
    if temp[k+1] > temp[k]:
        trend.append('up')
    if temp[k+1] < temp[k]:
        trend.append('down')
    if temp[k+1] == temp[k]:
        trend.append('nochange')

dftrend = pd.DataFrame(trend)

print(trend)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more pandas-like approach. We can get the difference of two consecutive elements of a series easily via [`pandas.DataFrame.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [2.5, 1.5, 3 , 3 ,4.8 , 4 ]})
df_diff = df.diff()

   Col1
0   NaN
1  -1.0
2   1.5
3   0.0
4   1.8
5  -0.8
```

Now you can apply a function elementwise that only distiguishes `>0`, `<0` or `==0`, using [`pandas.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

```
def direction(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 'up'
    elif x < 0:
        return 'down'
    elif x == 0:
        return 'nochange'

df_diff.applymap(direction))

       Col1
0      None
1      down
2        up
3  nochange
4        up
5      down
```

Finally, it's a design decision what should happen to the first value of the series. Here the `NaN` value doesn't fit any case. You can also treat it separately in `direction`, or omit in in your result by slicing.

---

**Edit**: The same as a oneliner:

```
df.diff().applymap(lambda x: 'up' if x > 0 else ('down' if x < 0 else ('nochange' if x == 0 else None)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 df['trend'] = np.where(df.Col1.shift().isnull(), "N/A", np.where(df.Col1 == df.Col1.shift(), "nochange", np.where(df.Col1 < df.Col1.shift(), "down", "up")))


   Col1     trend
0   2.5       N/A
1   1.5      down
2   3.0        up
3   3.0  nochange
4   4.8        up
5   4.0      down
```